# Ignore git files locally but do not remove them from the repository

Tags: wordpress, git

My team has is working on a git repository which contains a fully deployable Wordpress app. This was configured in this way so that it could be deployed to a AWS stack quite easily. The repository contains a caching plugin which creates two folders in the wp-content/ folder named

```
cache/
w3tc-config/
```

When devs are checking out this application they are removing the caching features for development and thus the plugin is writing these changes to the two directories it uses. Which then encourages .git to stage them for a commit.

Is there anyway we can ignore these folders on dev machines but not remove them from the repo? Also i'd be interested in hearing other solutions which might help me get round this problem even if it is a larger change.

Answer (score 1):

If you check out your repository and let `master` follow that, then you can create a `devel` branch where you just add cache w3tc-config to `.gitignore`.

I do something similar at work where I use git-svn to work with a svn repository which "links" in another svn repository for a sub module. Git clone did not fetch that sub module, so I just copied in the content from a svn checkout, checked into a devel branch (leaving master following the svn trunk branch), and added the sub module directory to .gitignore.

This is a solution that will require specific action from each developer, and not something you can push out from the repository. But similar to git hooks, if you create a `tools/do_it.sh` script that does the required actions it is possible to lower the bar considerably.

Comment: By creating a new branch wouldn't the .gitignore be staged for merging back into master when you want to make a push though?

Comment: Good point, it probably will (in my case, that is not an issue since upstream is SVN). I have not used `git rerere` myself, but from my understanding enabling that would make it possible to merge the first time, backing out the .gitignore changes, and then git will remember that for all coming merges.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have it both ways. Either the files are tracked or they are not. You cannot keep files in the repository but avoid tracking changes to them. Once they are tracked, it is up to you to not `git add` them. (And it is worth noting that git does not track folders ever.)

Create an archive called `UnzipMeRightAfterCloning.zip` that contains all the stuff you want ignored. Anyone cloning the repo needs to extract that archive, and it will add all the files/folders blocked by your `.gitignore` settings. (And given your current setup, you will have to untrack the files in those folders first.)

Put these in your `.gitignore` file. (Do not put in asterisk.)

```
cache/
w3tc-config/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a local `.gitignore` file in the project directory.
in the file paste the following

```
cache/*
w3tc-config/*
```

Now, these files will be excluded from git, but they won't be removed from the repository.

Comment: These files need to be in the repository. Just optionally excluded on the dev end. This is not a viable solution for my problem.

Comment: if they were already pushed, it won't take them out. it just ignore the changes and won't display them in git status

Comment: They are already pushed and need to be. The question is really how a dev working on the repo can manually ignore those folders when committing back to the project locally.

Comment: This only stops git from tracking *new* files. It has no effect on tracked files.